# "fatal error: TProcessor.h: No such file or directory" when trying to install Rhbase package

Tags: ubuntu, hbase, rstudio, rhadoop

everyone, 
I'm trying to install Rhbase package, but first I was missing thrift package, what I solved, but now it shows me another error. I added TProcessor.h into ../lib/cpp/src/thrift/processor/ but it didn't help and it shows me the same error:

```
    In file included from Hbase.cpp:7:0:
    Hbase.h:10:24: fatal error: TProcessor.h: No such file or directory
    #include <TProcessor.h>
                           ^
    compilation terminated.
    make: *** [Hbase.o] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rhbase’
```

I am using RStudio
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You should edit `thrift.pc`.

I used `locate thrift.pc` and found it in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/`.
Then I edited it so that the `includedir` variable looked like

```
includedir=${prefix}/include/thrift
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check where is your threft.pc file

pkg-config --cflags thrift

if its in the therft directory move using this commands

cd /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

sudo perl -pi -e 's{(^includedir=.*/include$)}{$1/thrift}' thrift.pc

sudo perl -pi -e 's{(^Cflags:.*)}{$1 -std=c++11}' thrift.pc

and find whether ur thrift is in this directory.

pkg-config --cflags thrift

-std=c++11 -I/usr/local/Cellar/thrift/0.9.2/include/thrift

Or in some relevant directory based on your system configuration.